# How do I roll back my iOS version? The 12.2 update has broken my WiFi

Tags: iphone, ios

When I updated my iPhone 8 to 12.2 (16E227), it broke the WiFi and now apps like YouTube can't connect and often times I can't even load apple.com in Safari. When I restart the phone then it works for about a minute. When I turn airplane mode on and off, it works for about a minute.

However my iPad with iOS 9.3.5 works flawlessly. My Samsung laptop works flawlessly. Also when I turn WiFi off on my iPhone and use cell data, it also works.

Comment: It shouldn't have broke your wifi like that. Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling the apps? Have the apps with problems been updated since iOS 12.2 came out? The only way you could possibly revert is by having an iTunes backup of the phone when it was on the previous version. You can't use iTunes and a 12.1.4 IPSW file because Apple is no longer signing that version.

Comment: @DrZoo - Restoring a backup doesn't restore the iOS that was on the device when the backup was made. It will restore onto the current iOS.

Comment: Sorry, but at least on AD we have a full-spec duplicate QA to refer to, which SU doesn't have [as it's off-topic on there] The issue isn't that the file is verifiable, it's that Apple will not authorise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't.

Apple stop signing previous versions shortly after a new one comes out. iOS 12.1.4 is no longer signed since April 4.

Ref: MacRumors - [Apple Stops Signing iOS 12.1.4 Following Release of iOS 12.2](https://www.macrumors.com/2019/04/04/apple-stops-signing-ios-12-1-4/)

I would look elsewhere for your solution, because had it been a widespread issue it would be well reported by now.

Comment: OK but that doesn't make any sense. A signature is a static sequence of bytes. If you are familiar with cryptography, a signed file is just another file that uses the signer's private key. You don't "stop signing" something because signing a file is a one-time event, not an ongoing process. As long as you have the file, the file's signature, and the public key, you have a signed, verifiable file.

Comment: It's an ongoing & well-established process. Installing an iOS needs connection to Apple's servers. The servers sign the iOS 'live' to your device to activate it. If Apple will no longer sign it, you can't activate & use it. You can call it a 'handshake' if you'd prefer, but Apple refer to it as signing.